# Eigenvalue and eigenvector problem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

I am looking to get to the [answer](http://postimg.org/image/5rwljrz69/) of [Question 3 e)](http://postimg.org/image/xht6kpo0h/). I successfully expand the determinant to -λ^3 + 6λ^2 + 3λ - 13 using the characteristic equation and this is where I get stuck. I tried rational root theorem, synthetic division, factoring, yet I still can't get the roots and hence the answer in the end. Any solutions or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: The roots of that cubic [aren't anything nice](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%CE%BB^3+%2B+6%CE%BB^2+%2B+3%CE%BB+-+13%3D%3D0). I suspect you're supposed to find them numerically and work from there. Which makes it a rather ugly question, but there's nothing we can do about that :-).

Comment: So, how do I find the roots, without plotting the equation? Maybe I didn't do synthetic division right, since it should probably work.

Comment: I assume this is some sort of educational exercise. Are you allowed to use calculators, computers, etc.?

Comment: Not graphic calculators and no other electronics.

Comment: Hmm. That seems pretty horrible. The numbers in the solution you linked to are indeed the eigenvalues of that matrix (I didn't check the eigenvectors) so it doesn't seem like there's an outright mistake. I notice that they only ask for *one* eigenvalue and its corresponding eigenvector, and that one of the eigenvalues is a lot bigger than the others -- there is a method that would exploit this, but I don't know whether you've been taught it.

Comment: Well, I don't know, but I'd like to hear more about it.

Comment: MrYouMath, I haven't explicitly checked Kevin's determinant but I *have* checked (1) that the characteristic equation he gives has approximately the roots stated in the answer he linked and (2) that the matrix in his question has approximately those eigenvalues. If he got the determinant wrong, that would be quite some coincidence.

Comment: Kevin, it's called the "power method". Suppose you take a "random" vector v and repeatedly multiply it by your matrix B. Your vector will be some linear combination of the eigenvectors of B, and multiplying it by B will multiply the coefficients by the corresponding eigenvalues. So if one eigenvalue is much larger than the others, after doing this many times your vector will be close to being an eigenvector of B; specifically, the one with largest eigenvalue.

Comment: So now you can hit it with B again and see how much bigger it gets. You can save some effort in the first bit by first computing some power of B and then operating with that instead of with B. Though if you're doing it by hand the saving will be offset by having to work with larger numbers in the matrix.

Comment: In principle, this can go terribly wrong, because it can happen that the coefficient of that "largest" eigenvector in your original v is zero, or at least very small. In that case you'll still end up finding an eigenvector and eigenvalue but they won't be the ones you want. You can also get in trouble if it happens that there are two or more eigenvalues that are close to being "largest".

Comment: So to do it this way and know you've got it right, you'd need to (1) estimate the eigenvalues -- e.g., by evaluating that characteristic polynomial at a few suitably chosen values of $\lambda$ -- then (2) pick a vector that's easy to work with and likely to be pointing in roughly the same direction as the eigenvector of the biggest eigenvalue -- in this case (1;0;0) would be an obvious choice -- then (3) hit it lots of times with B and see how things grow, (4) observe that the growth is faster than any of the smaller eigenvalues would permit.

Comment: From that it follows that you do indeed have a reasonable "amount" of the main eigenvector there. Then verify that what B is doing is close to a scalar multiplication, and maybe look at the eigenvalue estimates you get from a few successive multiplications-by-B. That's enough to be handwavily convincing, but still falls short of an actual proof...

Comment: This is a 3x3 matrix. You don't need to pull out the big dogs to handle it. Cauchy-Hamilton will do nicely. SInce the three eigenvalues are distinct, the eigenvector of $\lambda_1$ is a column of $(B - \lambda_2I)(B - \lambda_3I)$, and similarly for eigenvectors of $\lambda_2, \lambda_3$.